Is it possible to do a simultaneous subscript and superscript in XMGrace for like yping out chemical symbols
Am trying to type out chemical symbols but couldn't find anything online that helps.
I have tried \SA\sZ\NX but doesn't seem to allow me to simultaneously show the subscripts and superscripts in the same position like for chemical symbols.

Of course you can: as always with xmgrace, as long as you accept that things will get much more complicated :)
As detailed here, you can use \h{XXX} to shift by XXX the text that follows. Here an example (X\SA\N\s\h{-0.7}Z):

